# Meaning of an image on Feynman's shirt

Tags: soft-question, notation

Is there any physical meaning  of the image on Feynman's T-shirt?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Surely there is a story behind the print on Feynman's tee, these are the CM-1/CM-2 T-shirts. Quoting [Tamiko Thiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamiko_Thiel):

> The geometric boxes and their 'hard' connections represent the 12-dimensional 'cube of cubes' that forms the internal hardware network connecting all processor chips with each other in a maximum of 12 steps. Feynman is the one who suggested this structure, and I played with the topology until I came up with this representation, which can be expanded for an infinite number of dimensions.

They were also a part of Jobs's think different campaign.

References:

http://www.mission-base.com/tamiko/cm/cm-tshirt.html

http://www.mission-base.com/tamiko/cm/tshirt/

Comment: Note: the diagram only actually describes 6 dimensions (3 dimensions in each cube, and 3 inter-cube dimensions).

Comment: @Angew [This woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamiko_Thiel)